# Installing hooks as pre-push instead of pre-commit

Tags: git, githooks, git-push, pre-commit.com

I have a pre-commit hook defined as follows in a `pre-commit-config.yaml` file located in the root of my repository -

```
repos:
-   repo: https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8
    rev: 3.7.9
    hooks:
    - id: flake8
```

This works as expected and blocks any commit if I am now following flake8 rules. However, I want to do this for a `git push` and not for a `git commit`. One way I found is to add a `pre-push` file inside `.git/hooks/` and do `flake8 .` from inside. This does the job but now I can't share that file with anyone through git since the `.git` folder is not tracked by git.

Is there any file/config that I can put in the root of the repo that will act as a pre-push hook?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen since this is about `pre-push` support in [pre-commit.com], which [is supported](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-during-push)

Comment: Woah, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I didn't know you had this option in pre-commit.